# targeting a[aria-expanded="true"] on just one #Id element

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have Bootstrap 4 dropdown via a hyperlink and also have dropdowns on my sidebar. They are using the a[aria-expanded="true"] as part of the styling.

Sadly however this is making the element below have a black background which I need for my sidebar but not for the button.

[image]

I have tried using the following but this isn't working

```
#pageSettings a[aria-expanded="true"]{
  color: #243B55;
  font-weight: 400;
  background: initial!important;
}
```

and this is the underlying html

```
<a id="pageSettings" href="#" class=" mr-3" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-ellipsis fa-lg"></i></a>
<div class="dropdown-menu shadow">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="<?php echo URLROOT.'/permissisions/setpermissions/'.$data['pageHeader']['pagePermName']; ?>">User Permissions</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="<?php echo URLROOT.'/permissisions/grouppermissions'; ?>">Group Permissions</a>
</div>
```

I'm missing the correct syntax to only have the styling for that specific element but can't seem to find any way of getting it to work.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Based on your HTML code above there is no `a` in `#pageSettings`. The `a` *is* the `pageSettings`. So `a#pageSettings` is probably what you are looking for? You can remove the PHP code and use the `[<>]` button to make your code an interactive example.

Answer (score 0):

As Peter pointed out in the comments I didn't need the 'a'

This now works for anyone else

```
#pageSettings[aria-expanded="true"] {
  color: #243B55;
  font-weight: 400;
  background: initial!important;
}
```